# how does gitlab-runner [runners.docker] volumes work?

Tags: docker, gitlab, gitlab-ci, gitlab-ci-runner

according to the doc, I config runner:

```
[[runners]]
  name = "docker-dind"
  url = "http://127.0.0.1/"
  token = "KhrzNHQc19_NME-WDgTW"
  executor = "docker"
  [runners.custom_build_dir]
  [runners.cache]
    [runners.cache.s3]
    [runners.cache.gcs]
    [runners.cache.azure]
  [runners.docker]
    tls_verify = false
    image = "docker:20.10.9"
    privileged = true
    disable_entrypoint_overwrite = false
    oom_kill_disable = false
    disable_cache = false
    volumes = ["/certs/client", "/cache"]
    shm_size = 0

    [[runners.docker.services]]
      name = "docker:20.10.9-dind"
```

it's working fine, but I want to know how it works, how service docker:dind shared "/certs/client" to job image docker

```
# Specify to Docker where to create the certificates. Docker
  # creates them automatically on boot, and creates
  # `/certs/client` to share between the service and job
  # container, thanks to volume mount from config.toml
```

Answer (score 0):

> how service docker:dind shared "/certs/client" to job image docker

It's the *runner* that specified the volume for both containers.

The runner is responsible for starting the job container as well as service containers, among other duties. This means the runner calls `docker run` (or some equivalent) to start your service containers and job container.

That is to say, a simplified version of the runner logic as pseudo code is something like:

```bash
for service in services; do
    docker run $service ...
done
wait-for-services
docker run $job_image ...
```

When you specify `volumes = ["/certs/client"]` in the `config.toml` it's the same behavior as if the argument `-v /certs/client:/certs/client` were passed to `docker run` when starting the service and job containers.

```bash
for service in services; do
    docker run -v /certs/client:/certs/client $service ...
done
wait-for-services
docker run -v /certs/client:/certs/client $job_image ...
```

Comment: thanks very much, I want to know how do I verify it.

Comment: @seqwait what exactly do you mean by "verify it"?

Comment: it seems like Runner creates all volume  and mount it to all service or job container